# Rooms/People management application database structure

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I'm trying to build an application which manages children's nurseries, specifically managing which child is in which room in the nursery at which point.

The Nursery chain has several branches. Each branch has several rooms, each room corresponds to an age range and has a limited capacity.

Children sign up to the nursery a month in advance and are booked in month blocks, so they have a start month and expected end month. They can be booked in on any particular day either AM, PM or both. So for example a child might sign up wanting to be booked in:

```
mon   AM
tues     PM
wed   AM PM
thurs AM 
fri   AM PM
sat   
sun   AM
```

The kid is 3 years old so either the room caterpillars or rabbits is suitable for him. I need to check that there's availability in those rooms and if so then make a record that this child is going to be booked into that room from month X to month Y.

So I have a table for children and a table for rooms but I'm finding it hard to figure out how to allocate children to rooms based on their age and basically how to record who is in what room.

I know it's probably simple but database structures always give me headaches!

What's the best way to set up my database to record children and rooms and who is where?

Answer (score 1):

The following structure should give you some idea of where to start. You can query the `children` table to find out how many children are assigned to a particular room at a particular branch and compare that to the capacity of the room declared in the `rooms` table. The `rooms` table also tells you the allowed age range.

In a real-world situation there are other things to consider: do all branches have the same rooms? If multiple branches have a "Rabbits" room are all of those Rabbits rooms restricted to the same age range and capacity? Can a child go to different branches or must they only go to the one they signed up for?

The answers to questions like that would probably affect the design of your database.

```
bookings
    id          unsigned int(P)
    child_id    unsigned int(F children.id)
    beg         datetime
    end         datetime

+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | child_id | beg                 | end                 |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2013-11-14 07:30:00 | 2013-11-14 19:30:00 |
|  2 |        2 | 2013-11-14 07:30:00 | 2013-11-14 19:30:00 |
|  3 |        1 | 2013-11-15 07:30:00 | 2013-11-14 19:30:00 |
|  4 |        2 | 2013-11-15 07:30:00 | 2013-11-14 13:00:00 |
|  5 |        2 | 2013-11-14 20:00:00 | 2013-11-14 22:00:00 |
| .. | ........ | ................... | ................... |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+

branches
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(20)

+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | North Branch |
|  2 | South Branch |
| .. | ............ |
+----+--------------+

branches_rooms
    id              unsigned int(P)
    branch_id       unsigned int(F branches.id)
    room_id         unsigned int(F rooms.id)
*branch_id and room_id form a unique composite key to prevent someone 
from saying the North Branch has multiple "Rabbits" rooms for example.

+----+-----------+---------+
| id | branch_id | room_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |
|  2 |         2 |       2 |
| .. | ......... | ....... |
+----+-----------+---------+

checks
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    child_id            unsigned int(F children.id)
    in                  datetime
    out                 datetime

+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | child_id | in                  | out                 |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2013-11-13 07:33:51 | 2013-11-13 17:34:13 |
|  2 |        2 | 2013-11-13 07:41:33 | 2013-11-13 17:22:18 |
|  3 |        1 | 2013-11-14 07:28:15 | NULL                |
|  4 |        2 | 2013-11-14 07:58:42 | NULL                |
| .. | ........ | ................... | ................... |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+

children
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    name                varchar(30)
    branch_room_id      unsigned int(F branches_rooms.id)
    beg                 date
    end                 date
    ...

+----+-------+-----+----------+-----+
| id | name  | branch_room_id | ... |
+----+-------+-----+----------+-----+
|  1 | Billy |              1 | ... |
|  2 | Susie |              2 | ... |
| .. | ..... | .............. | ... |
+----+-------+-----+----------+-----+

rooms
    id          unsigned int(P)
    name        varchar(20)
    min_age     unsigned int
    max_age     unsigned int
    capacity    unsigned int

+----+--------------+---------+---------+----------+
| id | name         | min_age | max_age | capacity |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+----------+
|  1 | Caterpillers |       0 |       3 |       10 |
|  2 | Rabbits      |       2 |       4 |       15 |
| .. | ............ | ....... | ....... | ........ |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Benny, thanks for taking the time to type all that out. I really appreciate it. To answer your Qus, each branch will have different rooms with different names. And a child can only go to the exact room they signed up to. But I think I can handle all that ok. It's the checking of how many children are in a room and when. So your checks table is a good idea. If I have a room with a completely unique id I can use it and the kid's id to store where they are. Before, I was thinking the start and end date would be in the children table. I think that's right Innit?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox - You might have a start and end date in the `children` table as well. The `checks` table is like a "timeclock" table - the child checks in when they get to the room and they check out when they leave. I don't think you asked for that but I was thinking about how my son's daycare works when I wrote this :-)

Comment: Humm... you gave me good food for thought. I don't think they need the checkin/out thing because they take attendance so that's not a prob. My main problem now is figuring out how to handle the itinerary that the kid wants. For example if a kid needs to be booked in monday am and pm, and thurs pm, then how am I meant to record that? All I can think at the mo is that I'd have another table, 'itinerary' with columns for monday_am, monday_pm etc... (as well as child_id) then either 1 or 0 in the entry. What you reckon? Thanks again for your input with this, very much appreciated :)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox - I edited my answer and added a `bookings` table. That would allow you to schedule a child from any time to any time. In my example data you can see that Susie is schedule for Friday Nov 14, 2013 from 7:30am to 1:00pm and then she comes back that evening from 8:00pm to 10:00pm (mom & dad must be having a "date night").